# Altair mark_line plots noisier than matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, altair

I am learning altair to add interactivity to my plots. I am trying to recreate a plot I do in matplotlib, however altair is adding noise to my curves.

this is my dataset 
[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbwSi.png)

linked here from github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leoUninova/Transistor-altair-plots/master/df1.csv

This is the code:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
for key, grp in df1.groupby(['Name']): 
  y=grp.logabsID
  x=grp.VG

  ax.plot(x,  y,  label=key)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()


#doing it directly from link
df1='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leoUninova/Transistor-altair-plots/master/df1.csv'


import altair as alt
alt.Chart(df1).mark_line(size=1).encode(
    x='VG:Q',
    y='logabsID:Q',
    color='Name:N'
)
```

Here is the image of the plots I am generating:
[matplotlib vs altair plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNpBx.png)

How do I remove the noise from altair?

Comment: I think that is not noise, please post your dataset.

Comment: I have made a new file df1 on github, which is the correct subset and makes it reproducible: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leoUninova/Transistor-altair-plots/master/df1.csv   I think the error might be related to the fact that the individual lines have 2 points for every VG value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altair sorts the x axis before drawing lines, so if you have multiple lines in one group it will often lead to "noise", as you call it. This is not noise, but rather an accurate representation of all the points in your dataset shown in the default sort order. Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'group': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q'
)
```

[image]

The best way to fix this is to set the `detail` encoding to a column that distinguishes between the different lines that you would like to be drawn individually:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    detail='group:N'
)
```

[image]

If it is not the grouping that is important, but rather the order of the points, you can specify that by instead providing an [order channel](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html#ordering-marks):

```
alt.Chart(df.reset_index()).mark_line().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    order='index:Q'
)
```

[image]

Notice that the two lines are connected on the right end. This is effectively what matplotlib does by default: it maintains the index order even if there is repeated data. Using the order channel for your data produces the result you're looking for:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leoUninova/Transistor-altair-plots/master/df1.csv')

alt.Chart(df1.reset_index()).mark_line(size=1).encode(
    x='VG:Q',
    y='logabsID:Q',
    color='Name:N',
    order='index:Q'
)
```

[image]

The multiple lines in each group are drawn in order connected at the ends, just as they are in matplotlib.